# Show user's orders in user's profile in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an online store, http://tabteb.com. It is based on ***wordpress*** and ***woocommerce***. I using **Ultimate Member** plugin for users registration and logging.
I want a plugin or a way that any user can see his **orders** in his profile.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: PHP, HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way - use woocommerce [my account shortcode](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-4). It will show last orders, and more info.

Example:

```
[woocommerce_my_account order_count="12"]
```

If you want to show all details of orders you should copy this file from woocommerce plugin templates/myaccount/my-orders.php to a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) folder woocommerce and then you edit the file to show all orders details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use this shortcode but it only show me the list of all orders and not showing all details of sale invoice.

Comment: I find a plugin for this, but it don't work in Persian language.

Comment: i added to my answer how you could edit the file displays the orders